# How to describe this navigation clearly in this software GUI?

Tags: sentence-construction

I need to say:

> After double clicking "login.feature" in "Package Explorer" panel, now **right click anywhere inside login.feature**, then context menu appears
> then go to "Run As" and click "Cucumber Feature"

My users should understand that they right click in this green area to get context menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click "login.feature" in "Package Explorer" panel to open the login.feature tab. **Right click anywhere in the tab's script area**. In the context menu that appears, go to "Run As" and click "Cucumber Feature".

Links regarding **script area** (or **scripts area**):

> [Image of script area and "right click in the script area"](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Emjb/scratch/scratch.6pp.pdf)
>
> [The Scripts Area is the area on the right side of the project editor where scripts are assembled...](https://test.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Eng:Scripts_Area#:%7E:text=The%20Scripts%20Area%20is%20where,separate%20scripts%20areas%20and%20scripts.)
>
> [The area where we type the code is called...](https://brainly.in/question/20616356)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply say:

> right click in the text area

This to reduce confusion, as "text area" obviously points to the area with the text, which is the green area. Simpler version:

> After double clicking "login.feature" in "Package Explorer" panel, now right click anywhere in the text area. The context menu will then appear, go to "Run As" and click "Cucumber Feature".